# Shipment's page customization removes UpdateIN Action

Tags: acumatica

I noticed that customizing the Shipment's page "Confirm Shipment" action, removes the "Update IN" action from the dropdown list. This is occurring even without actual logic in the overriden method - as soon as it's created and published, the action disappears.

Below is the list of steps that I have followed:

The Actions dropdown options for the Shipments page are:
[image]

Then, the following customization is created
[image]

Which - without any changes - generates the following result:
[image]

After publishing the customization, the Actions dropdown is now shown with the UpdateIN action removed:

[image]

I noticed that the UpdateIN action is not selectable in the Override Method option of the customization project - that could have some relation with the error:
[image]

The action definition however, can be found in the CodeRepository directory (with Visible = False):
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this issue has been fixed in 2017 R2 Update 3 (build #**17.230.0029**). Could you please update your developer instance to 2017 R2  Update 3 or more recent build and check if the issue gets resolved?